# Do characteristic functions characterize the independence of random variables? [Solved]

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence, characteristic-functions

It is well known that the probability density function characterizes the independence of random variables in the following sense.

$$X,Y \quad\text{independent}\iff f(x,y)=f_x(x)f_y(y)$$

where $f$ is the pdf of the random variable $(X,Y)$ and $f_x$ and $f_y$ are the pdfs of the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$, respectively. My question is, seeing as there is a bijection between characteristic functions and probability distributions, do characteristic functions also characterize independence? In the following sense

$$\varphi_{(X,Y)}(t_1,t_2)=\varphi_X(t_1)\varphi_Y(t_2)$$

where again $\varphi$ is the characteristic function of the random variable in its subscript.

Comment: Relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287138/moment-generating-functions-characteristic-functions-of-x-y-factor-implies-x/287321#287321

Comment: Thanks, that seems to solve the problem.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1802289/9464

Comment: Thanks for the comment, indeed, I had seen that page too linked in the one Clement provided.